# change item in the list with a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

```
dic = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
lis = ['a','b']
for c in lis:
    c = dic[c]
print lis
```

The list was not changed. I had expected that the list would be changed to `['1','2']`. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using indexes instead of a variable...

```
for i in range(len(li)):
    c = li[i]
    li[i] = dic[c]
print li
```

Also, never use `list` as a variable name..
or use `enumerate` like

```
for i, c in enumerate(li):
    li[i] = dic[c]
print li
```

or list comprehensions

```
lis = [dic[c] if c in dic else c for c in lis]
```

---

**Why not what you are doing?**
When you use `for x in y:`, `x` gets the value of an object/item in `y`
So, if you change the value of `x`, you don't change the value of `y[i]`, `i` being the index that you are on.

So, if you do this

```
>>> y = range(5,10)
>>> for x in y:
    i = y.index(x)
    x += 10
    print i
    print 'Value of x    : %3d, id: %7d' % (x, id(x))
    print 'Value of y[i] : %3d, id: %7d' % (y[i], id(y[i]))
    print '-'*31
```

You'll see the difference

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not how list iteration works. `c` is a new object at each iteration, and if you change that object, the original list is (thankfully!) not modified.

If you do want that, use `enumerate()`:

```
dic = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
lis = ['a','b']
for i, c in enumerate(lis):
    lis[i] = dic[c]
print lis
```

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing you are missing in your iteration is the fact that assigning the element to the name `c`, `c=dic[c]` re-binds `c` to a new object and does not update the original object in place. Consider the following Demonstration

```
>>> for i, c in enumerate(lst):
    print id(c), id(lst[i]),
    c=dic[c]
    print id(c)


4935168 4935168 4934712
4935192 4935192 5496728
```

So though before the assignment both the list element and `c` refers the same object within the list but assigning the value of the dictionary just changes the references

Note, here `id` just refers to the identifier of the object of reference

Note, as you are changing the entire list, its easier and faster to use List Comprehension

```
lst = [dic[e] for e in lst]
['1', '2']
```

**Warning** Don;t name a variable to a built-in

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
for c in myList:
    c = something
```

You are rebinding the name `c` to whatever "something" is, in this case the value at `dic[c]`. In order to get Python to actually "reach into" the list, you have to call a method on that list--the method `list.__setitem__()` tells Python to access the actual list object and *mutate* an item in that list, not to do a simple variable assignment.

```
for i, c in enumerate(myList):
    myList.__setitem__(dic[c])
```

This, of course, can also be written as (the more pythonic):

```
for i, c in enumerate(myList):
    myList[i] = dic[c]
```

It looks like a variable assignment, but it's not.